# CoreData using NSBatchInsertRequest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I'm trying to insert Array of dictionary in `CoreData` using `NSBatchInsertRequest` according WWDC 2019 (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/230/). The insertResult is nil, and my CoreData is empty.

```
let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "CoreDataPerformance", withExtension: "momd")!
let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "CoreDataPerformance", managedObjectModel: model)
container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
})

try container.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)

let moc = container.viewContext
moc.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
moc.perform {
    let insertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: Client.entity(), objects: clients)
    let insertResult = try? moc.execute(insertRequest) as? NSBatchInsertRequest
    let success = insertResult?.resultType
    print("RESULT STATUS: \(success)")
}
```

This is the error I receive in the console:

```
2020-02-04 18:30:25.800705+0200 CoreDataPerformance[62836:778869] [error] warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'CoreDataPerformance.Client' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.

CoreData: warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'CoreDataPerformance.Client' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.

2020-02-04 18:30:25.800846+0200 CoreDataPerformance[62836:778869] [error] warning:   'Client' (0x600000c50bb0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600001877480) claims 'CoreDataPerformance.Client'.

CoreData: warning:   'Client' (0x600000c50bb0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600001877480) claims 'CoreDataPerformance.Client'.

2020-02-04 18:30:25.800940+0200 CoreDataPerformance[62836:778869] [error] warning:   'Client' (0x600000c589a0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600001861680) claims 'CoreDataPerformance.Client'.

CoreData: warning:   'Client' (0x600000c589a0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600001861680) claims 'CoreDataPerformance.Client'.
```

Comment: The four lines in your call to `moc.perform`... have you attempted to run these without embedding in this perform closure - that is - delete the call to `perform`?

Answer (score 1):

your line `let insertResult = try? moc.execute(insertRequest) as? NSBatchInsertRequest`

should be:
`let insertResult = try? moc.execute(insertRequest) as? NSBatchInsertResult`

Answer (score 0):

The disambiguation issue is because you have multiple core data stacks open while the app is running. Is this because you have your app and a stack for tests? or because your app is using more than one?

Answer (score 0):

The error `CoreData: warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'CoreDataPerformance.Client' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.` means you have multiple entities in your model using the `Client` `NSManagedObject` subclass, there should only be one.

Another issue with your code is `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` does not work with batch requests because no did save notification is generated. You have to use `NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotification`, `NSPersistentHistoryChangeRequest` and `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` the technique is explained in [WWDC 2018 Core Data Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/224/) @ 21:57

Answer (score -2):

I think there's an error in the WWDC talk. Try doing this:

```
let insertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: Client.entity(), objects: clients)
try! moc.execute(insertRequest)
try! moc.save()
```

I used **try!** just so I can see any error. You can change it

Comment: NSBatchInsertRequest saves the object into the persistent store. I think you don't need to save the context explicitly. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest